# How do I move all my torrents from Transmission to Deluge?

Tags: transmission, deluge

What is the easiest way to move all my torrents? I'm not happy with Transmission's lack of features.

Comment: Speaking of features: I tried deluge, transmission, ktorrent and qbittorent. I like transmission and qbittorent best of all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Transmission stores torrent files in

```
~/.config/transmission/torrents
```

You can open the files found there with deludge.

Comment: You can also continue downloading `.part` files from transmission: make a backup of your `.part` files (just in case anything goes wrong), remove the `.part` extension, and place them on Deluge's downloads folder. Deluge will continue from where transmission stopped.